# Display two separate web pages simulaneously in single BlackBerry app

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, browserfield

I'm writing the HTML for a hybrid (iPhone/Android/Blackberry) mobile application. I'm not directly involved in the BlackBerry development side of things, but I am being told it is impossible to display two pages of HTML simultaneously on the same screen in a BB application like you can in iOS and Android. I can easily imagine why this would be true (memory and resource management, for example, or a singleton browser implementation). And I've definitely seen old postings in BlackBerry developer forums saying this is true. But I want to make sure we're not missing anything before we go down the road of porting some fairly detailed design work from HTML (which is finished and working) to Java.

Has anyone been able to put two browser instances (whether WebWorks or browserfield) on the same screen in a BlackBerry application? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) to display as many web-pages on the screen as you want.